# Rescued dog doesn't walk unless 2 persons come

Tags: dogs, behavior

I adopted a rescue dog 6 months ago, and she still doesn't walk unless there's 2 people with her.
She stops walking as soon as she exist the building and realises she is with 1 person. I tried carrying her a bit until she doesn't see the apartement anymore, but she would still stops and won't walk unless my partner comes.
Do you have some advice? :)
Thanks!